# Durandal - Activate viewmodels without the router

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I have the following setup for a module:

- Shell (has a router)

  - Workspace module

    - Screen1
    - Screen2

I want the workspace to show a couple of different views, collect information from them, and POST some data to my api. I've started down the path of having a child router on the workspace, but that means the screens are *so* decoupled that I have no means of getting at the screen viewmodel objects. This means I have no way to communicate back to the workspace that they've done what they needed to. I'm also concerned about the "lifestyle" of the various viewmodels - I'd do something like `import workspace = require('workspaceViewMode');` but I'm not sure what instance of the workspace that would get.

What is the correct approach? Is a child router actually the best method, or should I be trying to use the "activator" (struggling with docs for that) directly?

Answer (score 0):

Well from trying it out and poring over the documentation, it does seem that because the workspace has a child router, it's instance stays around during navigation. I tested this by having it assign itself a guid on activation, and checking that guid on the imported instance in each screen viewmodel.

So my solution is to provide methods on the workspace for the screens to call, whereupon the workspace will decide what to do with them.

*Phew!*